# Calculating random sample points using polar coordinates on cartesian map

Tags: python, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I'm trying to generate random sample points on a cartesian plane using polar coordinates. I have a cartesian map with polar sectors, I'd like to put a random sample point within each of the sectors.

[Problem Visual Description](https://i.ibb.co/1MxMNzp/problem.png)

I've added a sample point in the first sector. The problem is I don't know how to set the min and max limits for each sector as it's a cartesian plane (using cartesian min and max of the sector corners will give you boxes instead of the entire polar sector).

[image: https://i.ibb.co/Vj9yW8m/system-Gen.png]

Code is commented for clarity. Final output posted below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 10]
import math
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections as mc
import pprint
from IPython.utils import io
from random import randrange, uniform

#convertes cartesian x,y coordinates to polar r, theta coordinates
def cart2pol(x, y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    return np.array([rho, phi])

#convertes polar r,theta coordinates to cartesian x,y coordinates
def pol2cart(r, theta): #r is distance
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    return np.array([x, y])

#cooks delicious pie
pi = np.pi

#no idea what this does
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi,100)

#x theta
def x_size(r):
    return r*np.cos(theta)

#y theta
def y_size(r):
    return r*np.sin(theta)

#calculates distribution of sectors on a circle in radians
#eg. sub_liner(3) = array([0.       , 2.0943951, 4.1887902])
def sub_liner(k):
    sub_lines = []
    for c,b in enumerate(range(0,k)):     
        sub_lines = np.append(sub_lines,((12*pi/6)/k)*c)
    return sub_lines

#calculates all distribution sectors for every ring and puts them in a list
def mlp(i):
    master_lines = []
    k = 3
    for a in range(0,i):
        master_lines.append(sub_liner(k))
        k += 3
    return master_lines

#calculates all four corners of each sector for a ring
#(ring,ring points,number of rings)
def cg(r,rp,n):
    return [[[pol2cart(r-1,mlp(n)[r-1][i])[0],pol2cart(r-1,mlp(n)[r-1][i])[1]]\
  ,[pol2cart(r,mlp(n)[r-1][i])[0],pol2cart(r,mlp(n)[r-1][i])[1]]] for i in range(0,rp)]

#generates all corners for the ring sectors
def rg(n):
    cgl = []
    k = 3
    for r in range(1,11):
        cgl.append(cg(r,k,n))
        k += 3
    output = cgl[0]   
    for q in range(1,10):
        output = np.concatenate((output,cgl[q]))

    return output

#print(cg(1,3,10)[0][0][0])
#print(cg(1,3,10))

# randrange gives you an integral value
irand = randrange(0, 10)

# uniform gives you a floating-point value
frand = uniform(0, 10)

#define ring sectors
ring_sectors = rg(10)

#define node points
nx = 0.5
ny = 0.5

#define ring distance
ymin = [0]
ymax = [1]

#generate rings
ring_r = np.sqrt(1.0)
master_array = np.array([[x_size(i),y_size(i)] for i in range(0,11)])

#plot rings
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
[ax.plot(master_array[i][0],master_array[i][1]) for i in range(0,11)]
ax.set_aspect(1)
size = 10
plt.xlim(-size,size)
plt.ylim(-size,size)

#generate nodes
ax.plot(nx, ny, 'o', color='black');

#ring lines
lc = mc.LineCollection(ring_sectors, color='black', linewidths=2)
ax.add_collection(lc)

plt.grid(linestyle='--')

plt.title('System Generator', fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```

Sample output can be viewed at.

**Edit:**

What I've tried:

Based on feedback, I implemented a system which gets random uniform values between the polar coordinates, and it works, but the points aren't neatly distributed within their sectors as they should be, and I'm not sure why. Maybe my math is off or I made a mistake in the generator functions. If anyone has any insight, I'm all ears.

[Output with points](https://i.ibb.co/LpknRzR/system-Gen2.png)

```
def ngx(n):
    rmin = 0
    rmax = 1
    nxl = []
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 1
    k = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        for a in range(0,rmax*3):
            nxl.append(pol2cart(np.random.uniform(rmin,rmax),\
                                np.random.uniform(sub_liner(rmax*3)[(s1+k)%(rmax*3)],sub_liner(rmax*3)[(s2+k)%(rmax*3)]))[0])
            k += 1
        rmin += 1
        rmax += 1

    return nxl

def ngy(n):
    rmin = 0
    rmax = 1
    nyl = []
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 1
    k = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        for a in range(0,rmax*3):
            nyl.append(pol2cart(np.random.uniform(rmin,rmax),\
                                np.random.uniform(sub_liner(rmax*3)[(s1+k)%(rmax*3)],sub_liner(rmax*3)[(s2+k)%(rmax*3)]))[1])
            k += 1
        rmin += 1
        rmax += 1

    return nyl

#define node points
nx = ngx(10)
ny = ngy(10)
```

Comment: Why not generate a point and if the distance to the origin is less than the radius, specify that as the point?

Comment: The points need to be randomly distributed within the sector. But your comment did give me an idea,  generating the point using r and theta, with r max as the max distance and r min as the min distance. I can then convert that polar coordinate to cartesian coordinates.

Comment: If you choose to go down that route, you should compute the radius as square root of a uniformly random number, otherwise you will have many more points close to the origin

Comment: Ah, interesting. That might be part of the issue I'm having with the distribution at the moment.